# PyCharm shows matplotlib-plot in console, but not in script

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to python and i'm using pycharm

My problem with matplotlib is that the code :

```
import scipy.misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = scipy.misc.face(gray=True)
plt.imshow(image)
```

Works in console (i have the popup window with the image), but does not work when i run a file with the same code in it. No error (exit code 0), but no popup.

Ideas ?

Comment: Did you forget to show the window via `plt.show()`?

Comment: aaaaand i feel like a idiot. Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 0):

As point out in the comment, one have to add plt.show()

Sorry !